# How to modify history lines in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

As the answer of a [question I asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/787350/why-there-is-an-empty-line-begin-with-in-the-result-of-history-command-on-li) mentioned:

> History lines which have been modified, are shown with a * at the beginning of the command, provided that mark-modified-lines property has been turned on in ReadLine configuration.

now I wanna know how to modify history command line in linux or in what situation the history command is called been modified and shown with a "*" instead of in the history output?

Comment: If you want to _disable_ this feature see: https://superuser.com/questions/302230/how-to-prevent-bash-from-altering-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're talking about bash, you can modify history lines pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> until you find the line you want to modify, then edit the line and press <kbd>Down</kbd> until you're in a new line. That effectively changes history :)

[image]

Comment: What puzzles me most is how the "*" in the history output comes from.

Comment: What puzzled me most is where does the "*" in the output of history command comes from?

Comment: That is just the shell's way of telling you that line has been modified. This was on your linked question.

Comment: But when I modify the history command through key up and key down, there is no "*" showing up in the history output. In what situation the shell thinks the history has been modified? That I wanna know.

Comment: `Up`, `Backspace`, `Down`, `history`, `Enter`. You should have a modified entry in the history with a "*", indicating that you have modified the previous entry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Could you show me the operations to the history that let the "*" show up in history output? Thanks first.

Comment: I added a screencast to the post.

Comment: How did you make that screencast?

Comment: @user3872279 If you really want to modify history for whatever reason and **not** have it marked with an asterisk, use a text editor to change `~/.bash_history` and the line you want to change. This will also carryover to another shell session, whereas the mentioned method does not.

Comment: Many thanks for your patient and brilliant answer. I've got that.

Comment: @user3872279: if this was the correct answer and you liked it, please mark it as accepted and upvote it :)

Comment: @JasonC: I will make a tutorial about it, and I'll comment here as soon as I finish it :)

Comment: @ValmikyArquissandas Ok